# Как сгинерировать ЧПУ (alias/slug) по полю title с другой таблицы используя SlugableBehavior

Tags: php, yii2

Есть 2 таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE news
(
    id int,
    alias varchar(255),
    ...
);
```

и

```
CREATE TABLE news_translate
(
    id int,
    news_id int,
    language varchar(16)
    title varchar(255),
    content text,
    ...
);
```

, а также соответствующие им модели News и NewsTranslate (для хранения переводов). Есть пару языков en и ru.

Моя задача, что бы при создании нового или редактировании уже имеющегося перевода для новости генерировался ЧПУ по полю news_translate.title  в поле news.alias по дефолтному языку(например en).
Я начал использовать SlugableBehavior

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'slugAttribute' => 'alias',
        ],
    ];
}
```

но не могу указать в его настройках поле с другой таблицы/модели.

> 1) Можно ли указать атрибут/поле с другой модели по связи или еще как
>   нибудь в данном поведении?
>
> 2) Не хотелось бы писать свое поведение.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что поле из другой модели можно получить через анонимную функцию в свойстве uniqueSlugGenerator. Не тестировал:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        [
            'class' => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'slugAttribute' => 'alias',
            'uniqueSlugGenerator' => function ($baseSlug, $iteration, $model)
            {
                // newsTranslate - relation
                return $model->newsTranslate->title;
            }
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо, то что нужно!